# R - Building package is very slow due to dataset

Tags: r, package

I'm building a small package with R and this is the basic structure

```
├───inst
│   └───app
│       ├───help
│       ├───processed
│       ├───rawdata
│       └───www
├───man
├───presentation
├───profiles
├───R
│   ├───connection
│   ├───graphics
│   ├───modules
│   ├───nmf
│   │   └───data
│   └───utility
└───tests
```

`inst` contains a Shiny app while `R` contains other functions useful for the shiny app itself.

My problem is that the folder `processed` and `rawdata` contains `rds` files and they are quite big ( a couple of GB in total) so **building package is very slow**.

I added to .RBuildignore these two lines

```
^inst\app\rawdata$
^inst\\app\\processed$
```

but it seems that when i click "Install and restart" in Rstudio, R doesn't ignore these two folder .
When I click the button first command being launched

```
devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))
```

then it runs

```
Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source DataDesk
```

Am I getting something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried forward slashes in `.RBuildignore`, e.g. `^inst/app/rawdata$`?

Comment: You could also run "Build source package" from the RStudio Build menu, then install that from the Packages menu.  If this speeds things up, the steps could be attached to a hotkey.

Comment: Have you thought of splitting your package into 2 packages. 1 for the data and 1 for the code? Since data doesn't change so often there would be no need for including this in the code package.

Comment: I even use usethis::use_build_ignore("inst/app/processed") to add to .RBuildignore but R doesn't seem to exclude the folder